# Не сохраняются картинки на сервере Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload

Выдаёт такую ошибку.

> Can't write image data to path (uploads/img.png)

Вот код

```
if(Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $file = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save('uploads/img.png');
}
```

Когда в строке

```
$file = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save('uploads/img.png');
```

Убираю Uploads и сохраняю просто в папку public, то всё работает, как решить эту проблему?
Использую библиотеку Intervention Image

Comment: Думаю не `__DIR__` надо использовать, а пути предоставляемые laravel https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/helpers#%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `__DIR__` в путь:

```
 $file = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save(__DIR__ . 'uploads/img.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

если надо сохранить в папку storage

```
$file = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save(storage_path('uploads/img.png'));
```

если надо сохранить в папку public

```
$file = Image::make($file)->resize(300, 200)->save(public_path('uploads/img.png'));
```

Comment: и не забывайте про разрешения (chmod) записи в эти директории